# How can i return distance from google maps directions?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am fairly new to android and i have been following [this tutorial](http://www.newthinktank.com/2015/01/make-android-apps-24/) on getting maps to display.

i was wondering is there a way that when you get the directions you can return the driving (not straight line) distance between point A and B and have it displayed in a text view?

Thanks.

Comment: You could use the Distance Matrix API (part of the Web APIs) in order to get the distance.  Note you can specify the mode (driving, walking, etc).  See documentation here:  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
float[] result = new float[0];
Location.distanceBetween(startLatitude, startLongitude, endLatitude, endLongitude, result);
//The computed distance is now stored in results[0].
```

[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html)

Also you can use [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/):
It has static method to compute distance.

```
SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(from,to)
//Returns the distance between two LatLngs, in meters.
```

[Source](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/)

Comment: Note that this is just the distance of a straight line between two points.  I believe the OP wants the distance of the driving directions from point A to point B.

Comment: @DanielNugnet Yes that's right, would like if possible to the distance to drive.